# Any PHP Frameworks that use a Layout and Block system like Magento?

Tags: php, layout, frameworks, magento

While it is most typically touted as a fully-featured shopping cart system, Magento is an awesome framework to boot. Of particular awesomeness is the layout system. In essence a page is created from "Blocks" which all inherit from an abstract class which does not assume the use of template files. These blocks are assembled according to a layout which is the composition of a bunch of XML files being merged together to describe a hierarchical structure of blocks for each page (inheritance supported for DRY). I love this system but Magento is a very heavy framework.

Are there any other frameworks which use a similar system? I.e. layouts that are defined outside of the template files as described above. PHP 5.3 is preferable but would consider frameworks in other languages.

Comment: Every MVC framework has a "View" class of some sort, but most of these amount to essentially PHP's 'include' method with some helper methods.   Magento's layout and block system is far beyond that.. Is there seriously no other framework that even comes close?

Comment: I would also like to the question regarding static and non static blocks like in magento... I cannot find any other framework which has similar backend panel and these nice features.

Comment: The only backdrop is that magento really is heavy weight.

Comment: @ColinM what was your final decision at the time (probably Magento-Lite) and 2 years from when you asked this question what would be your decision now?

Comment: @ColinM I've worked on Magento a couple of years and it's been nice. Recently i've started working in Symfony2 which is also nice with template inheritance and all but I would like to implement Magento style layouting in Symfony2 so I was browsing for resources on the subject.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Yes, I stuck to Magento-Lite and I have not looked back once. Looking into the future Magento 2 and Oro Platform look like promising platforms. Magento 2 is not yet stable. Oro recently released a release candidate for OroCRM so I'm guessing Oro Platform is now fairly stable.

Comment: I'll work on a  mage-like "layout+blocks" implementation, I'll let you know of my progress if you're interested. I'm targeting it for Symfony2 but I'll write it as an independent component (perhaps a require for the xml/yml config reader component).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would stick with magento if you already managed to get your head around it. Why waste time learning another system? If speed is the problem, spend some time on optimising magento (there is a [whitepaper](http://www.magentocommerce.com/whitepaper/) on the subject which is a good place to start) and look into installing [apc](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/8937/). It gives my magento installations a hell of a boost.

Comment: I've done a lot of system optimization already, even using apc.stat = 0 in production but it is still pretty slow. Such is the price of a good framework I suppose. -Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not strictly a framework, But [Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/278173) pretends to be a web-application-framework. You can strip Drupal to its bare bones and develop your own modules on top of it. Using its blocks system and templating engine.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, Zend Framework can definitely be modified to allow for a Magento-style layout engine, and it doesn't have to be as complex a customisation as Magneto probably makes it.

In fact, I was so compelled to have this myself, and not let it beat me, I decided to start implementing the same form of layout engine myself in my own library I use for Zend.

From this came my first blog post on my new blog, and my first ever post on SO

BTW, thanks for bringing ModMan for Magento to life Colin.

[Building a Magento-style Layout Engine for your Zend Framework Library](http://avidonline.co.nz/building-a-magento-style-layout-engine-for-your-zend-framework-library/)

Comment: Cool, any chance you are going to put your work on github so I can watch it?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **[Symfony Templating](http://components.symfony-project.org/templating/)** component. It is fast, lightweight and powerful.

If you don't like PHP code inside templates, try **[Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/)**.

Both libs are standalone, support template inheritance and are easily extensible.

Comment: Symfony Templating is very nice.. However, there seems to be no designated way to inject content into a slot from outside of the template files (e.g. add a block to a sidebar from a controller). Seems like $this->add('sidebar','more content here') would do the trick so that could probably be extended easily.

Comment: You can embed slot content from anywhere: inside template $this->set('sidebar', 'sidebar content...'), and from controller $engine->set('sidebar', 'sidebar content...'). But if you want to APPEND content to a sidebar, just concatenate it, e.g.: $engine->set('sidebar', $engine->get('sidebar') . ' appended content');

Comment: Symphony doesn't have a backend panel and static blocks etc... AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

Look at Symfony 2.0, it still in beta. http://symfony-reloaded.org/

Comment: Symfony 2 appears to essentially be HMVC like Kohana 3, which is nice, but HMVC doesn't handle extensions and injections like Magento's block system. Also, Symfony's "->extend" methodology tightly couples a view to a layout which kinda defeats the purpose of HMVC...

Answer (score 1):

The [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) is one such framework, which has almost the same structure as Magento and uses the correct MVC architecture (as many other versions of MVC architectures exist, which are implemented in many available PHP frameworks).

However, the Magento framework has been greatly modified by Varien, to suit its requirements, thus providing support for controlling templates & modules using XML configuration files. Also I think that this is Magento framework's unique characteristic feature.

So, all in all, I think Magento (with its barebones) must be used as you already are using & so does "silvo".

Hope it helps.

Comment: Standalone Zend definitely does not come close with respect to Magento's layouts and blocks system, but so far it looks like you are right, Magento must be unique in this way. However, I'll hold off on accepting an answer for a while longer in hopes that there are still some good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on CakePhp. It uses layout system. Also there is elements that you can create blocks on layout. It may work for you. Also not so hard to learn.

Comment: They're called "Elements", but the idea is the same.

Comment: CakePHP appears to be the same as the others.. a view class that is essentially a glorified "include"

Comment: But unlike Magento, CakePHP will not be able to control the template files using the layout XML. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Knowledge_Craving I don't know much about Magento. But Cake has not XML style layout. It uses ctp files for viewing. You may be right.

Answer (score 0):

Magento is build on [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/). So, you may use this framework. But these days, almost all php frameworks use layouting system.

You can also consider [Yii Framework](http://yiiframework.com) and [Doo PHP](http://doophp.com/)

Comment: The typical MVC framework layout system (including Zend, Yii and Doo) is not even close to Magento's layout system..

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you take a look at Agavi http://www.agavi.org as it sounds like it does what you want.

Comment: Agavi's layers and layouts come close, but it appears they are pretty much static once defined. Also, it seems the nested views can only be "pulled in" rather than injected unless I missed something. Magento's layouts can be extended and modified on the fly and blocks such as a sidebar can easily be extended purely via the layout system.

Comment: You can also define them at runtime. Layouts are merely a convenient way of pre-defining the most common use cases. It's perfectly normal for applications to define different slots in different views, especially on the innermost layer (typically named "content"); think dashboards with a bunch of widgets or something.

That of course also means you can always pass instructions regarding what sub-slots to render to a slot that you execute.